# In c++11, how can I call std::max on a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, initializer-list

I have a `vector<data>` (where `data` is my own pet type) and I want to find its maximum value.

The standard `std::max` function in C++11 appears to work on a collection of objects, but it wants an initializer list as its first argument, not a collection like `vector` :

```
vector<data> vd;
std::max(vd); // Compilation error
std::max({vd[0], vd[1], vd[2]}); // Works, but not ok since I don't vd.size() at compile time
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) overloads are only for small sets known at compile time. What you need is [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) (which is even pre-11). This returns an iterator to the maximum element of a collection (or any iterator range):

```
auto max_iter = std::max_element(vd.begin(), vd.end());
// use *max_iter as maximum value (if vd wasn't empty, of course)
```

Comment: It looks like this answer is still valid. [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) can't handle a vector, only an initializer_list. It's because things like these that Pyhton is so superior for rapid prototyping jobs. And I can't believe that also accepting a vector may have an impact in terms of performance of std::max.

Answer (score 2):

Probably with lambda more flexibly

```
vector<data> vd;

auto it = max_element(vd.cbegin(), vd.cend(), [](const data& left, const data& right)
    {
    return (left < right);
    });
```

You just should implement operator of compare for your type "data" via `data::operator < ()`